# Stop a Jquery/Javascript timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this can't be that difficult, but I swear I can't find a straight forward answer to this. I have the following javascript/jquery function that starts a timer:

```
function startTimer() { (function ($) {
    //timer for the box
    window.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
       $(".region-brand-window").timer();
    }, 10000);

    jQuery.fn.timer = function() {
       changeBrandOnTimer();
    }
})(jQuery); }
```

How do I stop this thing? And I don't mean pause. I mean turn it off from another function.

Comment: `clearInterval(timer)` should do it. Or if timer is defined in the scope your using it in, you could do `clearInterval(window.timer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clearInterval(window.timer);
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 2):

To cancel an interval, you would use:

```
clearInterval(window.timer);
```

FYI, if it was a timeout  you would use `clearTimeout()` in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

use [window.clearInterval(intervalID)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval)

```
window.clearInterval(window.timer)
```

Answer (score 1):

call stopTimer whenever you want to stop timer.

```
    function startTimer() { (function ($) {
        //timer for the box
        window.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
           $(".region-brand-window").timer();
        }, 10000);

        jQuery.fn.timer = function() {
           changeBrandOnTimer();
        }
    })(jQuery); } 

   function stopTimer(){
           clearInterval(timer );
   }
```